# MONACAでアプリ内の内部リンクに関しまして

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

現在、WordPressで作ったサイトのアプリ化を行っています。

トップページからsingle.htmlにURLパラメータを渡してそのパラメータに対応するJSONを引っ張ってきて記事タイトルや記事文を表示させているのですが、その際、記事内に内部リンクがあった場合リンクを押すとブラウザが立ち上がってしまうのをやめてJSONで引っ張ってきたデータをアプリ内で表示したいです。

なにかいい案はございませんでしょうか。

以上、不躾な質問で恐縮ではございますがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

リンクがクリックされた時の処理をJavascriptで奪う方法が有効なのではないかと思いました。

jQueryを利用した方法は以下になります。

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    location.href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    return false;
  });
</script>
```